# How to render is TREE JSON using underscore.js each loop?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I created collection inserting type of JSON TREE.

**view.js**

```
views.Livingword = Backbone.View.extend({
      render: function(templateName) {
        var template = _.template(templateName);
        this.$el.html(template({result : this.collection.models}));
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(model){
          console.log(model.attributes.bathroom);
        });
        return this;
      }
```

My collections are set they are the picture below.
[image]

I want to know how access the model.attributes (that is mean how to access each object?)

I entered `console.log` statement that's like`console.log(model.attributes.bathroom);`

The results are shown below.
[image]

How to access this attribute using underscore.js `each` in html??
I really want that its solution.

---

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your question but, it seems like you don't know how to browse the inner object of your model attributes?

Comment: Yes,  it's correct what you said.

Comment: ok is model.attributes an array or an object?

Comment: My model was consist of object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, maybe it is what you want

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(model){
      console.log(model.attributes.bathroom); 
      for(var i in model.attributes){
       if (model.attributes.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        console.log(model.attributes[i]);
       }
      }

    });
```

Comment: yes! that's right way but, can I ask you one more thing? 
how to use model.attributes.hasOwnProperty in html? for example, <% _.each(result, function(model){ %> ?

Comment: yes something like that, read this article https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2411-using-underscore-js-templates-to-render-html-partials.htm I think that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

simply :

```
model.get('bathroom');
```

Comment: Hmm.. I didnt try that lol i will go home and try your answer.